# Iterate each element's sub-element and compare the inner text

Tags: c#, .net, xml

I have an xml document as follows:

```
<customerList>
<customerRecord>
    <customerName>David</customerName>
    <customerAge>25</customerAge>
    <customerAddress>1, Walking Street, 3000 Las Vegas</customerAddress>
    <customerPIC>
        <picList>
            <picName>Rose</picName>
            <picPosition>supervisor</picPosition>
            <idType>1</idType>
            <idNumber>90001000</idNumber>
        </picList>
        <picList>
            <picName>James</picName>
            <picPosition>supervisor</picPosition>
            <idType>2</idType>
            <idNumber>90002000</idNumber>
        </picList>
    </customerPIC>
    <customerCompany>Facebook</customerCompany>
</customerRecord>
    <customerRecord>
    <customerName>Carrie</customerName>
    <customerAge>25</customerAge>
    <customerAddress>2, Dancing Road, 2000 New Mexico</customerAddress>
    <customerPIC>
        <picList>
            <picName>Maisie</picName>
            <picPosition>secretary</picPosition>
            <idType>1</idType>
            <idNumber>90003000</idNumber>
        </picList>
        <picList>
            <picName>John</picName>
            <picPosition>HR</picPosition>
            <idType>2</idType>
            <idNumber>90004000</idNumber>
        </picList>
    </customerPIC>
    <customerCompany>Uber</customerCompany>
</customerRecord>
    <customerRecord>
    <customerName>Dexter</customerName>
    <customerAge>25</customerAge>
    <customerAddress>3, Hugging Street, 3000 New Orleans</customerAddress>
    <customerPIC>
        <picList>
            <picName>Jill</picName>
            <picPosition>PA</picPosition>
            <idType>1</idType>
            <idNumber>90005000</idNumber>
        </picList>
        <picList>
            <picName>Alex</picName>
            <picPosition>supervisor</picPosition>
            <idType>2</idType>
            <idNumber>90006000</idNumber>
        </picList>
    </customerPIC>
    <customerCompany>Google</customerCompany>
</customerRecord>
```

In short, I want to compare each idNumber of each picList in each customerRecord agains the picString = "90001000". Since in each customer record will have two picList, if any of those idNumber is not equal to picString. I need to delete that customerRecord.

For now, I'm using code as follows. Since the picString can be in either one of both picList, I'm stuck thinking of how can i do the comparison, without risking deleting every customer record.

```
string picString = "90001000";

foreach (XmlNode customerRecord in customerList)
{
    XmlNode customerPIC = customerRecord.SelectSingleNode("//pic:customerPIC", nsManager);

    foreach (XmlNode picList in customerPIC)
    {
    XmlNode idNumber = picList.SelectSingleNode("//pic:idNumber", nsManager);
    string idNumberString = idNumberString.InnerText;

    if (idNumberString != picString)
        customerRecord.RemoveAll();
    }
}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a flag to determine if a `picString` equal to "90001000" was found.

```
string picString = "90001000";

foreach (XmlNode customerRecord in customerList)
{
    XmlNode customerPIC = customerRecord.SelectSingleNode("//pic:customerPIC", nsManager);

    //let's consider the picstring wasn't found by default, for each customerRecord.
    bool isPicStringFound = false;

    foreach (XmlNode picList in customerPIC)
    {
        XmlNode idNumber = picList.SelectSingleNode("//pic:idNumber", nsManager);
        string idNumberString = idNumberString.InnerText;

        if (idNumberString == picString)
            isPicStringFound = true; //we found it ! no need to delete
    }
    //no picString found ? delete !
    if (!isPicStringFound)
        customerRecord.RemoveAll();
    //at next loop, the flag will be reset
}
```